# query with parse is too slow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm doing a query for retrieve some data from Parse, I have the query in a external class called Exercise, not in the tableViewController and the code is the following:

```
// LOAD
var arrayExercise:[Exercise] = [Exercise]()


func loadAll() -> [Exercise] {

    // Esercizio di load
    let exerciseName:Exercise = Exercise()
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Exercise")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo:(PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!)


    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {

                    // Add the name of the Exercise into the array
                    let text:String? = (object )["name"] as? String

                    exerciseName.setNome(text!)

                    self.arrayExercise.append(exerciseName)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    return arrayExercise
}
```

And in the TableViewController I call this method in the viewDidLoad but I noticed that the tableView load before the query is completed and it result empty! I tried to add the tableView.reloadData() into the query but it doesn't work! How can I load the query and then show the tableView? Thank you!

Comment: the `reloadData`-approach normally is the the correct way to go.

Comment: @luk2302 but I in an external class, not in the uitableview on, how can I do a reloadData from another class?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Android, I don't know if it can help, but in my case it was because the query was being done in the background, so it did't wait for the query to be done, so the data wouldn't appear as expected, I solved it by not using the query in background instead using a "normal" query, in Android was something like this:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> resultsitems = ParseQuery.getQuery("ClassName").whereEqualTo ("Column", x);

    try {
        objects=resultsitems.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't know how Parse for IOS works, but my guess is that is something similar, so try searching for the right syntax for that, and hopefully it will work as you want.